# Prove convergence of $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x)}{1-x^2} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm really lost about how to prove the integral converges.
I tried using the fraction expansion theorem and got to
$$ \frac{\ln(x)}{1-x^2} = \frac{\ln(x)}{2(1+x)} + \frac{\ln(x)}{2(1-x)}$$
But I didn't find a way to use it.
I can't use the Dirichlet's test or Comparing tests since the function is not positive.

What am I missing?
Thank you in advance and have a nice day!

Comment: Though $\log x<0$ in $(0,1)$, $-\log(x)$ is positive in that interval. In other words, $|\log x|=-\log x$ on ($0,1)$. Let $f(x)$ denote your integrand. Close enough to  $0$,  $1-x^2>\frac12$ and so $|f(x)|<2|\log x|$, A simple calculation shows that $-\int^1_0\log(x)\,dx<\infty$. Close to $1$, by virtue of L'Hospital rule for example, $|f(x)|<3/2$ and the constant function $g(x)=3/2$ is convergent.

Answer (score 3):

Noticed that $\ln x\leq x-1$ when $0<x\leq 1$,and
$$\int_0^1\frac{x-1}{1-x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^1\frac{x-1}{(1+x)(1-x)}\mathrm{d}x=-\int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x}=\left[\ln|1+x|\right]_0^1=\ln 2 $$
converges, so $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1-x^2}\mathrm{d}x$ converges.

Comment: It requires a lower bound, not upper bound.

Comment: But $lnx\le x-1\le 0$ and for comparison test we need $f(x) \ge g(x) \ge 0$

Answer (score 2):

The intgrand is $f(x):=\dfrac{\ln(x)}{1-x^2}$, with $x\in(0,1)$ so you have
$$f(x)\sim\begin{cases} \ln(x)&&x\in\mathcal U(0^+)\\\dfrac{x-1}{2(1-x)}&&x\in\mathcal U (1^-)\end{cases}$$
and this clearly shows that $\int_{[0,1]}f(x)<+\infty$ since both terms of the asymptotic have convergent integral respectively in a neighbourhoof of $x=0$ and $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not the best approach but it’s quite funny

We know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{1}/{n^2}$ converges (it’s easy to prove), now I will split up this sum into even and odd terms

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4n^2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2} $$
$$\implies \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} =\frac{4}{3} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2} = \frac{4}{3} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2} $$

You can use integration by parts to check that $$\int_1^0 x^{2n}\ln x\,dx=\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$$
So our sum becomes
$$S= \frac{4}{3} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_1^0x^{2n}\ln x\,dx= \frac{4}{3} \int_1^0\ln x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{2n}\,dx$$

Since $0<x<1$ we can use the geometric series formula, Hence $$S= \frac{4}{3} \int_1^0\frac{\ln x}{1-x^2}\,dx$$

Since $S$ converges, this immediately implies that $$\int_1^0\frac{\ln x}{1-x^2}\,dx= -\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1-x^2}\,dx $$ converges as well.

Comment: Although justification of all this is easy if one is aware of Monotone convergence, the OP may not be aware or familiar with Lebesgue integration. In terms of improper integrals, there are easier justifications.

Answer (score 1):

Let us substitute $t = \ln(x)$ that is $x = e^t$ and therefore $\mathrm dx = e^t \mathrm dt$ and thus the integral becomes

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{te^t}{1-e^{2t}}\,\mathrm dt
$$

which can also be written as

$$
-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ze^z}{e^{2z}-1}\,\mathrm dz
$$

by substituting $z = -t$.

Now, when $0<z<\infty$, observe that

$$
\frac{ze^z}{e^{2z}-1} > \frac{ze^z}{e^{2z}}
$$

since denominator is smaller in LHS and therefore

$$
-\frac{ze^z}{e^{2z}-1} < -\frac{ze^z}{e^{2z}}
$$

Now,

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}ze^{-z}\,\mathrm dz = 1
$$

converges and thus $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1-x^2}\mathrm{d}x = -\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ze^z}{e^{2z}-1}\,\mathrm dz $ also converges.

Answer (score 0):

It can be shown that $ I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x^2-1}dx\in(0,\frac32)$. While the lower bound is evident, the upper bound is established as follows

\begin{align}
I& =\int_0^1  \frac{\ln x }{x-1}dx -\int_0^1 {\frac{x\ln x}{x^2-1} } \overset{x^2\to x}{dx} = \frac34\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x-1}dx\\
&= \frac34\left(2I +\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x+1}dx\right)
= -\frac32 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x+1}dx<-\frac32\int_0^1\ln x=\frac32
\end{align}